# Detect a change page and center the content on a webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I would like to detect a change of page in a `UIWebView` so that I can hide it when the user changes page.

I tried `if webView.loading` but it does not detect exactly when the page changes.
I would also like to hide the top and the bottom side of the page (either by deletion or by automatically centering the page).

Comment: Please verify my edit, and add more detail. Your questions isn't about Xcode, but as you reference it an iOS I assume you mean a UIWebView and that you are writing code in obj-c or swift (confirm), and you need to detect users tapping on links?

Comment: My question is about xcode with obj-c (sorry i forgot to mention this) i need in the UIWebView to detect when users tapping on links or when users change page like this : "if user click/load a new page" : hide the UIWebView" for now i do this : "if webView.loading" : "webView.hide = YES" but with loading view hides long time after loading :/

Comment: I wan't also delete/hide some content of the UIWebView if it's possible or juste force centering the view if i can't do otherwise.

Comment: The delete/hide should be a new question with a good amount of detail about what is to be deleted (it's probably a javascript question).

Answer (score 0):

You need a class which is the web view delegate. This delegate needs to implement `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` so it can find out about new load requests. This will tell you what location the request is for (`request`) and why it was requested (`navigationType`).

Comment: My second question in details : i would like to hide/delete some content loaded by the UIWebView like this for example : http://imageshack.com/a/img661/1874/kZfcBw.png i only want to keep the content in the red rectangle. How can i do this ? Thanks.

Comment: That depends on the web page. You would need to load javascript into the web page or rely on the site being responsive.

Comment: In my example with the google page how can i only keep the rectangle ? I need it to load the page faster by hiding useless things.

Comment: To load the page faster you would need a server in the middle to trim the HTML to remove image references and large blocks of text I guess, but this is really a very different question about html and javascript (create a new question and tag apprriately)

Comment: I create a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306851/hide-content-on-a-uiwebview i give more details.