# Hide content on a UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, hide

I'm working on an application for iOS in Xcode, i want to hide some content of my page and keep only the center of it.
E.g : http://imageshack.com/a/img661/8407/X5KuuN.png.
If it's too complicate to hide contents, it would be enough to force the page to be at the center, in the middle of the page (user can't move the page and the page will load in the center).

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can't open your image. Just insert it into your question

Comment: I need 10 reputation to send image :/ but i can add a new link : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/06/1422993983-screen-shot-2015-02-03-at-20-02-29.png

Comment: Are you trying to include the iCloud page or is it your own site you want to include?

Comment: This is just an example, i want a code that works for every site. E.g : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/06/1423146960-screen-shot-2015-02-03-at-20-02-29-2.png. I juste want to keep only the center of the site.

Comment: I want the page loads in the center instead of on top.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove/modify the unwanted `DOM` elements by "injecting" javascript at webViewDidFinishLoad stage with  `[yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: yourJSCodeString]` function.